# как внутри круга написать текст?

Tags: svg

```html
<svg version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100"
 style="border:1px solid crimson" viewBox='0 0 50 50'>
  <circle r="20" cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="" stroke="#03BE9B" stroke-width="2"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте тег `<text>`. Для него можно указывать css свойства

```html
<svg version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100"
 style="border:1px solid crimson" viewBox='0 0 50 50'>
   <style>
    .text { font-size: 10px; fill: white; text-transform: uppercase;}
  </style>
  <circle r="20" cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="" stroke="#03BE9B" stroke-width="2"/>
  <text x="12" y="28" class="text">text</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: есть способ тег <text> ставить по середине по гизонтали и вертикали ?